# LUA command to move items to bank from bags in WoW Classic

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I have this nifty little lua command to move all ore to my bank:

```
/run for b=0,4 do for s=1,GetContainerNumSlots(b)do if strmatch(GetContainerItemLink(b,s),"Ore")then UseContainerItem(b,s);end; end; end;
```

But I can't figure out how to make it move Ore and Stone.
I am still pretty new to lua, and "or" statements have me pretty flummoxed.
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lua
/run for b = 0, 4 do for s = 1, GetContainerNumSlots(b) do local link = GetContainerItemLink(b, s) if link:match("Ore") or link:match("Stone") then UseContainerItem(b, s) end end end
```

Comment: That works beautifully, thanks.
 I had been playing around with adding an "or" in there, but it didn't work. This works though, so my syntax must have been wrong.

Thanks for the speedy reply and fix to my problem :-D

Comment: You shouldn't use stackoverflow for syntax questions though. It's considered low effort

Comment: Sure thing @ketho. In that case, can you please give me an example of a Google search that would give me this answer, please? i tried searching, but couldn't find anything. Saying something is low effort without showing how easy it would have been to find the answer elsewhere is pretty low effort.

Comment: You're right, see PIL on Logical Operators https://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html